# How to deploy more than one sharing rule in one deployment?

Tags: deployment, sharing, criteria-based-sharing, sharing-rule

If I keep two criteria based sharing rules in Account.sharingRules XML file, there is a deployment error in start line of the the second rule: **sharing operation already in progress**.

How do we deploy more than one sharing rule in one deployment?

Comment: Perhaps sounds like a Salesforce issue? Organizations deploying a large number of sharing rule changes would have problems if this affects all organizations.

Comment: Do you need to make the deployment more than once?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can ask support to enable a feature called [Defer Sharing Calculations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_defer_sharing_calculations.htm&language=en). That way, you can suspend sharing rule calculations to not have them run immediately after you have deployed them, but at a time that suits you better.

Comment: @dphil Did you manage to deploy this way? Actually kinda curious, never used it myself.

Comment: I'll hand you the bounty anyways... but the client decided to just manually create it instead so honestly I don't know.

Comment: To confirm, enabling Defer Sharing Calculations solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error "**sharing operation already in progress**" occurred in our case when an object sharing model was changed (from public to private sharing) and 36 sharing rules were added to same deployment package.

Another workaround to the error is to split the deployment package :

- deploy the change in sharing model first
- then deploy all sharing rules

This solution is helpful for orgs with high volume of data whereby suspending sharing rule calculations and resuming them can take longer to proceed.