# Pushing multiple sharing rules to Scratch Org. Turning on Defer Sharing Calculations

Tags: deployment, sharing, salesforcedx, criteria-based-sharing

We have a huge problem with deploying multiple criteria based sharing rules to an existing scratch orgs.

Push is either failed (when there is new stuff added additionally to those sharing rules) or partially succeeded with errors:

> sharing operation already in progress

After some search I found one answer that could probably help: [How to deploy more than one sharing rule in one deployment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83692/how-to-deploy-more-than-one-sharing-rule-in-one-deployment/123558) but this solution in this answer involves asking support to turn on specific option and we probably can't afford to wait for support for each new scratch org.

So the question is: Is there any possibility to turn on this feature using Scratch Org config file? I went through all of options briefly but didn't find anything helpful. Or maybe someone know another solution for this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: More info here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/268450/62835